What's the idiomatic way to waste the output of a generator in Python?
Sometimes I need to consume everything that a generator outputs but don't actually need the output. In one case, some callers need progress updates from a coroutine, but some callers don't; in another case, some callers need to iterate through the results but some callers only need the side effects.
What's the idiomatic way to do this?
I currently use list():
def do_work_and_yield():
    for x in ...:
        y = do_work_on(x)
        yield y

def only_cares_about_side_effects():
    list(do_work_and_yield())

but of course this is an abuse of list() and a waste of memory. I could write a loop:
def only_cares_about_side_effects():
    for _ in do_work_and_yield():
        pass

but what I Really Mean is just "run do_work_and_yield to completion", which the loop obfuscates.

Naturally, the solution was hiding in the standard library documentation. The itertools docs give a recipe for a function called consume that does just what I want.
The "recipes" in the itertools documentation are conveniently available on PyPI in the more-itertools package.
So now I can just write
from more_itertools import consume

def do_work_and_yield():
    for x in ...:
        y = do_work_on(x)
        yield y

def only_cares_about_side_effects():
    consume(do_work_and_yield())

